# umount - device is busy

Tags: mount

Sometimes when I want to umount a device, e.g.

```
sudo umount /dev/loop0
```

I will get the message

```
umount: /mnt: device is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
```

I usually solve this issue by closing a console window (in my case xfce4-terminal) and then `umount`.

What does this problem mean? Is there some smarter solution?

Comment: That happens for example if you are still in a shell in that directory to where the device is mounted.

Comment: I don't remember if I was there but I tried it and you're right, this happened.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It means that some process has a working directory or an open file handle underneath the mount point. The best thing to do is to end the offending process, change its working directory or close the file handle before unmounting.

There is an alternative on Linux though. Using `umount -l` calls a "lazy" unmount. The filesystem will still be mounted but you won't be able to see or use it, except for processes that are already using it. When the offending program exits (through whatever means) the system will "finish" unmounting the filesystem.

Comment: Is there a way to find out which process has the open file handle and should be terminated?

Comment: Using `lsof` is probably the best way.

Comment: e.g. `lsof | grep loop0`?

Comment: No, grep for the mount point. It should list any files underneath. I don't think it will show things that simply have a working directory under the mount point, so it isn't a perfect method.

Answer (score 24):

You can also use `fuser` to kill all processes using the mounted file system.

```
fuser -cuk /mnt
```

Options:

```
-c     
    Same as -m option, used for POSIX compatibility.

-u, --user
    Append the user name of the process owner to each PID.

-k, --kill
    Kill  processes accessing the file. Unless changed with -SIGNAL, SIGKILL is sent. An fuser process
    never kills itself, but may kill other fuser processes. The  effective  user  ID  of  the  process
    executing fuser is set to its real user ID before attempting to kill.kill.

-m NAME, --mount NAME
    NAME specifies a file on a mounted file system or a block device that is  mounted.  All  processes
    accessing  files  on  that  file  system  are  listed.   If  a  directory file is specified, it is
    automatically changed to NAME/. to use any file system that might be mounted on that directory.
```

Check for yourself at [explainshell](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=fuser+-cuk).

Answer (score 4):

I discovered a situation which can interfere with unmounting a device that I will share as an answer even though this question is very old.

If you have NFS shares being hosted on the machine, and any of those NFS shares are backed by the device you are trying to unmount, you will have to stop sharing them (best done by stopping the NFS service, e.g. `sudo service nfs-kernel-server stop` on recent versions of Ubuntu).  The NFS server may not show up in lsof or fuser, which can make the issue difficult to identify.

Answer (score 3):

Given your "usual solution", it means that the shell you have running in your console window has a directory in a file system on that device as its current working directory.

Linux, and Unixes in general, want very badly to keep a file system mounted if a process has a current working directory in that filesystem.

You could just use `cd` in the console window to get out of a directory in or under `/mnt` rather than killing the console window, and the shell running inside it.